# How to make jQuery scroll the page from #div to #div by clicking on the site navigation?

Tags: jquery, scroll, slider

Ok, I am working on a website which has fixed #sidebar and non-fixed #main_content. Now, what I need to do here is to make my #main_content part of the page scroll from div to div by clicking on a site navigation which is located at the sidebar. So if the user presses the "contact" button, the #main_content of the page auto-scroll to the #contact division.

I searched the net and found around 100 different jQuery sliders but nothing like this what I need. Any links, tutorials, ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use anchor hyperlinks and use jQuery to slide to them.

http://djpate.com/2009/10/07/animated-scroll-to-anchorid-function-with-jquery/

```
$('html,body').animate({
    scrollTop: $("#myLink").offset().top
}, 'slow');
```

Comment: Wow, that was fast! :D Now I see that there are so many solutions for this but I didn't use the proper search words before. Thanks!